# Random data-interval in carousel

Tags: javascript

It's there a posibility to change the timer of the image carousel so the images will change at random times?

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
})
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify what library you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: randomInt(1000, 5000)
});
```